# Where does Borland StarTeam ToolBar save its config data?

Tags: starteam

For some strange reason the Borland StarTeam Toolbar utility does not save its data (and thus does not cache/memorize the last used ST servers and is essentially completely useless). I thus have to log in manually each and every time I access ST, which is a nightmare.

Our IT folks have no idea, why on my system it does not save the data as it's supposed to. They claim, it's the first and only system showing this anomaly...

Any idea, where this toolbar saves the data to? Does it need some environment variable set to do this properly or something similar? Any pointer would be highly appreciated.

I am using this on a Windows 7 (x64 Ultimate) system, ST is v2009 (build 11.0.0-68), ST Toolbar is v11.0.0.38.

Answer (score 1):

You are running quite a mid-range build of the 2009 StarTeam Client.  I would recommend upgrading to the latest 2009 client,

http://supportline.microfocus.com/websync/STarTeam2009E.aspx

Current latest build is 11.0.0.91 and Windows 7 was only strictly listed as supported for builds 11.0.0.72 onwards.

Maybe the source of your issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to store some options under **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\StarTeam Toolbar**. But the login information appears to be stored somewhere else.

It's a dumb question, but are you sure that "Save as default credentials for this server" is checked when you login?

Comment: Yes - definitely! Our support even once walked me through since they didn't believe it. But the "effect" or "phenomenon" is, that - and apparently that's only on *my* system - the data does not get saved.